# Android Realm and on a null object reference in fragment

Tags: android, realm

I'm looking the answer of my problem. It's my first contact with Realm database and I have a problem with null object reference in fragment during saving data. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Helper method:

```
public void saveTask(final String text, final String date, final String time ) {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
            Task task = bgRealm.createObject(Task.class);
            task.setText(text);
            task.setDate(date);
            task.setTime(time);
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // Transaction was a success.
            Log.d(TAG, "ON_SUCCESS: Data Written Successfully");
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            // Transaction failed and was automatically canceled.
            Log.d(TAG, "ON_ERROR: Error");
        }
    });

}
```

OnClick method in fragment:

```
@OnClick(R.id.save_button)
public void onClickSave() {

    realmHelper.saveTask(title_text.getText().toString().trim(), date_text.getText().toString().trim(), time_text.getText().toString().trim());
}
```

Code inside onCreateView:

```
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).hideFloatingActionButton();

    Realm.init(getActivity());
    RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    realm = Realm.getInstance(configuration);
```

I tried solution with textview fields inside onClick method, but still same.

Comment: What is giving you the `null object reference`?

Comment: Method saveTask.

Comment: `realm` inside `realmHelper` is not initialized.

Comment: It is. The problem was in Helper constructor.

Answer (score 1):

From your `OnClick` method in fragment, I observe that you have a realm helper class which you created an instance of called `realmHelper`. Since you are using realm asynchronously I suggest you pass the instantiated realm object to the helper method or instantiate realm afresh in the helper method or class.

Passing the realm instance to the helper method

```
public void saveTask(Realm realm, final String text, final String date, final String time ) {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
            Task task = bgRealm.createObject(Task.class);
            task.setText(text);
            task.setDate(date);
            task.setTime(time);
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // Transaction was a success.
            Log.d(TAG, "ON_SUCCESS: Data Written Successfully");
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            // Transaction failed and was automatically canceled.
            Log.d(TAG, "ON_ERROR: Error");
        }
    });

}
```

Instantiating realm in the helper method

```
public void saveTask(Context context, final String text, final String date, final String time ) {
    Realm.init(context);
    RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration
        .Builder()
        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
        .build();
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(configuration);
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
            Task task = bgRealm.createObject(Task.class);
            task.setText(text);
            task.setDate(date);
            task.setTime(time);
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // Transaction was a success.
            Log.d(TAG, "ON_SUCCESS: Data Written Successfully");
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            // Transaction failed and was automatically canceled.
            Log.d(TAG, "ON_ERROR: Error");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I used yours both versions and the second one showing this error: android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
The error is still in saveTask method.

In the first solution error is: Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file.
So I removed code from onCreateView and it's null object reference.

Do you know maybe some comfortable solution for using Realm in fragment?
I can do it in Activity, but I really don't know what I'm doing wrong in fragment.

Comment: Wait lets clarify this. Is the helper method in a helper class or in the same activity? If possible show the different classes and activity in question so I can know what the problem is?

Comment: The problem was in constructor and I rebuild methods. It's fine now. Thanks for help.